# Can I use OpenUI5 and Svelte together?

Tags: sapui5, svelte, ui5-webcomponents

My question is basically the title.
So I've been trying to use them both but does it even make sense..?
Through a google search ui5 web components and svelte can be used but it's not the same thing...

Thank you

Comment: Short answer: no, not with OpenUI5. With UI5 Web Components, however, yes. Here is a sample Svelte TODO app with UI5 Web Components: https://github.com/SAP-samples/ui5-webcomponents-sample-svelte

Comment: Yeah it's what I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only confirm the answer provided by Boghyon H., but want to get more into detail. SAPUI5 and OpenUI5 can be considered frameworks themselves. Both bring a lot of built in functionality, aiming at building enterprise applications. Svelte on the other hand, to my understanding, is not designed specifically for business apps. I guess you can build one though.

Mixing up frameworks does not sound like a good idea.

And yes, UI5 Web Components fill this gap. I played around with Svelte and UI5 WC myself and quite like it.